# Filtered array returns empty, and I'm not sure why?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiview, nsarray

I'm using a PickerView to filter an existing array (called "Strains"), and the filtered array is called, "searchResults". Not sure why, but for some reason my app is saying that searchResults is empty (even though Strains is successfully populating). The `crash error` I get like this:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array
```

Any idea as to why? Code below. **Note: 'Strains' is being pulled from a MySQL database.**

**PickerViewController.m**

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
    {
        return 3;
    }

    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
        if (component == 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"you selected %@", [array1 objectAtIndex:row]);

        }

        if (component == 1)
        {
            NSLog(@"you selected %@", [array2 objectAtIndex:row]);

        }


        if (component == 2)
        {
            NSLog(@"you selected %@", [array3 objectAtIndex:row]);

        }




    }




    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
    {




        if (component == 0)
        {
            return [array1 count];
        }

        if (component == 1)
        {
            return [array2 count];
        }


        if (component == 2)
        {
            return [array3 count];
        }


    }

    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
    {

        if (component == 0)
        {
            return [array1 objectAtIndex:row];
        }

        if (component == 1)
        {
            return [array2 objectAtIndex:row];
        }

        if (component == 2)
        {
            return [array3 objectAtIndex:row];
        }


    }



    - (void)populateArray1
    {
        array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [array1 addObject:@"Arthritis"];
        [array1 addObject:@"Cancer"];
        [array1 addObject:@"HIV"];
        [array1 addObject:@"Migraines"];
        [array1 addObject:@"Insomnia"];

    }

    - (void)populateArray2
    {
        array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [array2 addObject:@"Nausea"];
        [array2 addObject:@"Pain"];
        [array2 addObject:@"Appetite"];
        [array2 addObject:@"Fever"];
        [array2 addObject:@"Exhaustion"];

    }

    - (void)populateArray3
    {
        array3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [array3 addObject:@"Oil"];
        [array3 addObject:@"Plant"];
        [array3 addObject:@"Edible"];
        [array3 addObject:@"Powder"];

    }

      if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pickerGo"])
    {

         NSLog(@"%@", Strains);


        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        PickerResultsTableViewController *PickerTableView = [(UINavigationController *)[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
         NSLog(@"%@", PickerTableView);


        NSPredicate *ailmentPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Ailment CONTAINS[c] %@", [array1 objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]];

        NSPredicate *actionPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Action CONTAINS[c] %@", [array2 objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]]];

        NSPredicate *ingestPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Ingestion CONTAINS[c] %@", [array3 objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:2]]];


        NSCompoundPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: ailmentPredicate,actionPredicate,ingestPredicate, nil]];

        searchResults = [Strains filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];


        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...

       [PickerTableView setSearchResults: [searchResults copy]];

                NSLog(@"%@", searchResults);
    }
}
```

**TableViewController.m**

```
- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *)tableview

{

    return 1;

}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (tableView == PickerTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];




    } else {
        return [Strains count];

    }



}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *strainTableIdentifier = @"StrainTableCell";

    StrainTableCell *cell = (StrainTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strainTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)


        cell = [[StrainTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strainTableIdentifier];



        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StrainTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];


    if (tableView == strainTableView) {
           NSLog(@"Using the search results");

            cell.titleLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
            cell.descriptionLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Description"];
            cell.ratingLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Rating"];
            cell.ailmentLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Ailment"];
            cell.actionLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Action"];
            cell.ingestLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Ingestion"];

            NSLog(@"%@", searchResults);
```

Comment: Have you tried printing `searchResults` right before `[strainTableView setSearchResults: searchResults];`. If so what prints?

Comment: Nothing prints in the console; just throws me the same error :/

Comment: An NSLog shouldn't throw an out of bounds exception. It should just give you empty braces...

Comment: Sorry, the NSLog did give me empty braces, but the error followed. Clearly my brain is slowly but surely turning to mush (I've been at this for HOURS)...

Comment: Well obviously your predicates are filtering out all of your data from your `Strains` array (also properties and variables should not be capitalized). This makes sense though, how can self's title contain three different selected row components? In your compound predicate you are using an `AND` operator, meaning that all three predicates must match to be added into `searchResults`.

Comment: I've changed SELF's [TITLE] to their actual names (left TITLE on all 3 by accident). What should I be using instead of the AND operator in this case then, assuming a result only needs to have 2/3 of the selected options?

Comment: Also: Not sure if this helps, but I added the code that I used to populate the Picker above as well.

Comment: @BrittanyL : where the exeption occurs?Please include the datasource and delegates of table?All else condition in picker datasource is waste remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
else
{
    return [array2 objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Should never be run, but if it is could break because the count uses `array1` and here you use `array2`.

For your predicates, `selectedRowInComponent:` returns an integer, but you're trying to use it like it returns an object. I'm guessing you want something more like:

```
    NSPredicate *ailmentPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Ailment CONTAINS[c] %@", [array1 objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]];

    ...
```

(Assuming that your `Strain` objects have a property called `Ailment`, and that you always have > 0 objects in `array1`).

Wherever the crash is you should be checking the `count` of the array before trying to use it.

Comment: See updated code above. Changed my predicates to match your code, and removed all else conditions in the pickerviewcontroller. Now the console says searchResults are being used, but the app still crashes saying searchResults is empty. Thoughts?

Comment: Nevermind, I FIXED IT :) IT WORKS! YOU ROCK! Just caught that I had an unnecessary if/else statement on my TableView. YAYYYY!

Answer (score 0):

```
    [PickerTableView setSearchResults: searchResults];
```

may be causing the trouble .It becomes deallocated when the next scene is loaded

make a copy of searchResults and use it

```
    [PickerTableView setSearchResults: [searchResults copy]];
```

Note:Implement `copyWithZone:` if You use customObjects in the array

Comment: Oh, you're definitely on to something :) Okay, so I implemented [PickerTableView setSearchResults: [searchResults copy]]; , and now my app doesn't crash. The console ALSO says it's "Using the Search Results". However for some reason the results aren't filtered; it just shows the entire list. Thoughts?